# After scroll visible coordinates for the objects in the UIScrollView

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a UIScrollView which contains 12 buttons. Only 5 buttons are visible at a time and rest all are not. When user clicks on a button i am animating a UIView from the position of the button. So when I scroll for hidden buttons and click view animation start from bottom from its original coordinates but not from the visible coordinates of the button.

When user scroll i want to know the visible coordinates of the button (contained in uiscrollview), so that I can animate from the button visible position. Or can anybody suggest which is the best way to implement this animation.

Note: My Scrollview is part of viewcontroller. I can't customize the scrollview as a parent class. Please help me asap to solve it as i am at the end of application development.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you perhaps include a screenshot, and the code where you are currently doing the animation that you're not happy with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved it using Scrollview `convertPoint:toView` API. Here is the solution:

`CGPoint aPtInScrollView = [viewA convertPoint:aPoint toView:self.view];`

- Where `aPoint` is the object in scrollview 'position